# Modal window doesn't resize in IE10 with extjs

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-10

I have a modal dialog in IE10 with extjs2. The layout gets resized on window resize just fine if it is a regular window, and does not resize if it is a modal window. As I can see, the body width and height is every time the same in JS code.

Comment: BTW, the page in in the IE8 compatible mode.

Comment: Why in IE8 compatible mode? Meanwhile Extjs is at version 4. If you want to sty compatible with modern browsers, you must probably update your code.

Comment: ExtJS 4.0.7, ExtJs 4.2 and any Internet Explorer (in particular IE 11). Modal windows cannot be dragged or resized. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.